# EKS step for new infrastructure

Tags: amazon-eks

How do I setup EKS for new infrastructure? We are currently using KOPS to manage **kubernetes** which is a big problem. We would like to move to AWS EKS.

How did we get to do this?

Comment: What's the "we" I keep hearing about? Did you forget to [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is originally developed by Google, it is open-sourced since its launch and managed by a large community of contributors. So, it's better to use GKE to deploy it.

Google Cloud Platform supports easy way to deploy using [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/) + [Helm](https://helm.sh/). You can use [TerraForm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) to deploy if you want.

To understand step by step GKE deployment, follow three topics below:

1. https://codeburst.io/google-kubernetes-engine-by-example-part-1-358dc84d425b
2. https://codeburst.io/google-kubernetes-engine-by-example-part-2-ee1f519a32f9
3. https://codeburst.io/google-kubernetes-engine-by-example-part-3-9b7205ad502f

If you want to use deployment manager together with [Helm](https://helm.sh/), you can follow the topic below:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/gitlab-continuous-deployment-pipeline-to-gke-with-helm-69d8a15ed910

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow!
You will find a super guide here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

I just checked KOPS docs and they apparently do AWS as well. I haven't worked with this tool before though.

Could you please describe a bit more what is the challenge? You can set up an eks cluster and then change your pipeline to go to the new one instead of the Google one.